# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context problem

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am a rookie swiftUI programmer that’s just getting started and I need help. I have recieved the error message “ Type of expression is ambiguous without more context” in my code but I have no idea why. The error message appears on the line of the font and font size of the TextbI have inputted afterwards. The error occurs whenever I try to declare my variables as Integer for calculation. When I convert back to string, The message goes away. Why? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI





struct ContentView: View {
@State private var weight: Double = 0
@State private var height: Double = 0
@State private var bmi: Double = 0

var body: some View {

    VStack{

        Text("BMI Calculator")
            .font(.largeTitle)

        HStack{
            Text("Enter Height")
                .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))


            TextField("Height (M) " , text: $height)
                .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        }

        HStack{
            Text("Enter Weight")
                .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
            TextField("Weight (KG) " , text: $weight)
                .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        }


        Button(action: {
            //Action of the button here
            let weightint = Int(weight.text!)
            let heightint = Int(height.text!)

            bmi = heightint / (weightint * weightint)
            print("testting")


        }) {
            Text("CALCULATE")
                .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 60))
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }

        //output

}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: bmi is a Double, you cannot calculate it using Int variables

Answer (score 0):

try this:

you made several mistakes regarding variables:

1) the textfield expects a String, not a double as variable.

2) some self. where missing too

3) Tipp: unfortunately the error messages in SwiftUI are not always pointing to your real problem - try commenting out your "new" code until it is successful again (you can compile it without errors), then step by step uncomment new lines and watch, when your errors happens...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var weight: Double = 0
    @State private var height: Double = 0
    @State private var bmi: Double = 0

    @State private var textHeight : String = ""
    @State private var textWeight : String = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Text("BMI Calculator")
                .font(.largeTitle)

            HStack{
                Text("Enter Height")
                    .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))


                TextField("Height (M) " , text:$textHeight)
                    .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }

            HStack{
                Text("Enter Weight")
                    .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
                TextField("Weight (KG) " , text: $textWeight)
                    .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 20))
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            }


            Button(action: {
                //Action of the button here
                let weightint = self.weight
                let heightint = self.height

                self.bmi = heightint / (weightint * weightint)
                print("testting")


            }) {
                Text("CALCULATE")
                    .font(.custom("DIN Condensed", size: 60))
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
        }

    }
}
```